# Can I use apple pay to perform deposit into application?

Tags: ios, react-native, applepay

I am developing a React Native casino application and am working on deposits for users. Currently I am doing some research and noticed that all the React Native libs that I saw, work on the principle that if you want to perform apple payment you have to have an item list and predefined price. I have the same thing in my memory for native (Swift or objective-c) inapp payments. But for my application I would need the user to insert custom amount, so I would need to have only someway to start transaction from a card user has in Apple pay to casino account and not inapp purchases. Is there a way to do that or if at least someone could give me a hint wwhat to google?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use in-app purchases for real-money gambling. See https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#gaming-gambling-and-lotteries  You may be able to use ApplePay. You would need to start by finding a transaction processor, such as Stripe, who can process your payments.  Gambling transactions are tricky due to the high rate of fraud, chargeback and regulatory issues.  Many companies do not wish to process them.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and like I said, I don't want in-app purchases since I have to have a list of them, but I want a way to simply deposit money on some custom amount that the player wants.

Comment: It isn't a question of what you want. It is a question of the App Store policies and how they apply to your app. You cannot use IAP for real money gambling. You will need to use some other payment processing solution. If the payment processor you select supports Apple Pay then you can use Apple Pay. Apple Pay is not in-app purchase.

Comment: Ok, thank you for explanation and help